# Angular2 + Html how to write code to if i enter character "A" in textbox it shows me A Enter

Tags: html, angular2-forms

Here i have Requirement like if i Enter any character in Textbox Its should be display me in Alter

```
  <input type="text" ()="Somevale("$event.target.vale")"/> //()=>what i mention
    Somevalue(value){
    alert(value)
    }
```

Comment: use change event and keep the alert() in the implementation for the change event handler

Comment: (change)="Someval()" its works on only wen i hit Enter btn but i need during run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Input event which will raise for every key input

```
<input type="text" (input)="Test(text.value)" #text>     

Test(name:any)
{
 alert(name);
}
```